# Android NDK: Linker Script .ld: OVERLAY : gives ld:4: malformed number: :

Tags: android, android-ndk, clang++

We are using a linker script in an Android project. Recently the NDK was updated from r20b to r25c. The linker script was using this syntax:

```
OVERLAY :
```

but this no longer compiled. It gave a syntax error:

```
ld:4: malformed number: :
```

So I changed the script into:

```
OVERLAY 0x0000 : AT (0x0000)
```

Now it compiles, but there is an undefined symbol (we did not have that problem when using NDK, but I assume that I can solve this as well).

I am not so fit with linker scripts.

My question basically is: now the syntax seems to be correct, but does it also semantically have the same meaning as before?